# Elasticsearch Python - No viable nodes were discovered on the initial sniff attempt

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I have a cluster of Elasticsearch nodes running on different AWS EC2 instances. They internally connect via a network within AWS, so their network and discovery addresses are set up within this internal network. I want to use the python elasticsearch library to connect to these nodes from the outside. The EC2 instances have static public IP addresses attached, and the elastic instances allow https connections from anywhere. The connection works fine, i.e. I can connect to the instances via browser and via the Python elasticsearch library. However, I now want to set up sniffing, so I set up my Python code as follows:

```
        self.es = Elasticsearch([f'https://{elastic_host}:{elastic_port}' for elastic_host in elastic_hosts],
                                sniff_on_start=True, sniff_on_connection_fail=True, sniffer_timeout=60,
                                sniff_timeout=10, ca_certs=ca_location, verify_certs=True,
                                http_auth=(elastic_user, elastic_password))
```

If I remove the sniffing parameters, I can connect to the instances just fine. However, with sniffing, I immediately get `elastic_transport.SniffingError: No viable nodes were discovered on the initial sniff attempt` upon startup.

`http.publish_host` in the `elasticsearch.yml` configuration is set to the public IP address of my EC2 machines, and the `/_nodes/_all/http` endpoint returns the public IPs as the publish_address (i.e. `x.x.x.x:9200`).

We have localized this problem to the elasticsearch-py library after further testing with our other microservices, which could perform sniffing with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing with our other microservices, we found out that this problem was related to the elasticsearch-py library rather than our elasticsearch configuration, as our other microservice, which is golang based, could perform sniffing with no problem.

After further investigation we linked the problem to this open issue on the elasticsearch-py library: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/2005.

The problem is that the authorization headers are not properly passed to the request made to Elasticsearch to discover the nodes. To my knowledge, there is currently no fix that does not involve altering the library itself. However, the error message is clearly misleading.